# Need to target Google APIs - unbearably slow emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

As any Android developer knows the ADT emulator is unbearably slow. This is solved by installing Intel's [HAXM](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager). However the app I am developing requires notifications to be sent from a server to my Android app, hence I am using GCM which requires that I target Google API as opposed to Android API. It seems HAXM doesn't work when you target Google API.

So without HAXM I am now trying to develop on an emulator that takes 5+ mins to load. How on earth do people who have to work with Google APIs develop on this, surely there must be a way to speed it up or get it working with HAXM?

Comment: I guess what people normally do, is to start the emulator and leave it running. That way you only have to take the 5 min startup once. You can deploy your Android application without restarting the emulator.

Comment: why not use a real device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am saving the emulator as a snapshot now and it is usable for development.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com) as a device to test. It's super fast and work with google API.

Answer (score 0):

There is this hack:

http://38911bytes.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-use-google-maps-api-in-android.html

Beware v21 of the SDK though as it looks like v21 breaks this hack with all of the emulator changes in v21. I'm reverting to sdk v20 now actually.